# Python convert files in directory one by one

Tags: python, loops

How do I convert all files in directory one by one with the code below?

This code takes all the files in a folder and converts them together, but uses up too much memory. I need to do it in the loop for each file separately.

i.e. Find file. Convert. Move. Repeat.

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
command = ('convert -compress LZW -alpha off -density 320 -depth 4 - 
contrast-stretch 700x0 -gamma .45455 *.pdf -set filename:base "% 
[basename]" +adjoin "%[filename:base].tiff"')

newpath = r'...'
new_dir = 'tiff'

if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    try:
        os.mkdir(new_dir)

    os.system(command)
except:
    print "The folder is already exist"


for file in glob.glob("*.tiff"):
    try:
        print('"' + file + '"' + ' has just moved to ' + '"' + new_dir + '"' + ' folder')
        shutil.move(file, new_dir);
    except:
        print "Error"
```

Comment: Not quite sure what this issue is. You are already moving files one at a time. Also as this seems to be a new project, you should use Python 3. Python 2 has been deprecated.

Comment: Yes but it works for all files in a directory at the same time, I need to do it for every each file separately: Find->Convert->Move then the next one and so on.

Comment: It already does that...

Answer (score 0):

using rename?

```
import os

os.mkdir("new_folder")

for file in ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']:

    os.rename(file,f'new_folder/{file}')
```